# Passing array of struct as parameter: Only libraries are allowed to use the mapping type in public or external functions

Tags: arrays, mapping, struct

I am trying to push multiple items to the array of structs in the contract. Couldn't find a clear answer if it is possible to pass an array of struct as a parameter.

Apparently I can't but I get a different kind of an error from the compiler. It thinks I am passing a mapping: `Only libraries are allowed to use the mapping type in public or external functions.`

Here's the code

```
mapping (address => Review[]) reviewsMap;
mapping (address => uint24) reviewCounts;

function addMultipleReviews(Review[] memory array) public {
    address author = msg.sender;
    for (uint i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
      reviewsMap[author].push(array[i]);
    } 
    reviewCounts[author] = reviewCounts[author] + array.length;
  }
```

Is this not allowed? If so what would be an alternative to add multiple Reviews?

Comment: You are not allowed to pass structs (or an array of structs in your case). What is `Review`? Instead of passing an array of this struct, pass several arrays, one for each one of the fields in this structure. Then construct a `Review` instance before pushing it to `reviewsMap[author]`.

Comment: Review is the struct defined in the contract. I already have an `addReview` function to add a single Review, which takes each single field as parameters, bundles them in a Review struct and pushes into the array.
`addReview(string memory a, uint32 b) public`

Is what you are suggesting passing arrays of fields as such?
`addMultipleReviews(string memory a[], uint32 b[]) public`

Comment: Yes. And at the beginning of the function, `assert(a.length == b.length);`.

Comment: Thanks. You can write it as an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to pass structs (or an array of structs in your case).

Instead of passing an array of `Review` elements, pass several arrays - one for each field in this struct.

Then construct a `Review` instance before pushing it to `reviewsMap[author]`.

I recommend asserting that the lengths of the arrays are identical.